# Using matplotlib and numpy, what is the simplest way to draw set of lines from vector of points ij to kl?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am learning about linear algebra and want to be able to draw lines to test things.  I am generally interested in a function that draws a line((i, j), (k, l)) on a graph. I will produce my points using numpy.

Most of my lines will be from (0,0) to (k, l).

I can manually input some basic stuff with good results:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

But now if I want to plot from (0,0) to a set of points xy, generated by random sampling from a uniform distribution, I am confused on how to restructure this data easily so that it makes sense to matplotlib. I am sure there must be a good "pythonic" way to do this.

```
x = np.random.uniform(0, 100, 5)
y  = np.random.uniform(0, 100, 5)
zeros = zip(np.zeros(5), np.zeros(5))  # 5 pairs at the origin
xy = zip(x, y)  # 5 pairs elsewhere

print xy
print zeros
plt.plot(xy)
plt.show()
```

Obviously, plot(xy) is not even close to the right answer!  How in the most straightforward way make lines from the 5 points in `zeros` to the 5 points in `xy`?

[image]

Comment: Wait, so you just want random lines all that start at origin x=0,y=0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a way to proceed to generate your start and end points. You will easily be able to modify the make_line() helper to generate and manipulate as many sets of points as you want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

line_number = 20

def make_line():
    x, y = (0, random.randrange(1000)), (0, random.randrange(20,1000))
    return x, y

for i in range(line_number):
    x, y = make_line()
    plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=2)

plt.xlim(0, 100)
plt.ylim(0, 100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, I'd just make a set of x points that's shared for all your lines.

```
x = np.linspace(0,20)
```

Then generate random y values, setting the first y value to 0 (so you have x=0,y=0 in your set)

```
linenumber = 10
for i in range(linenumber):
    y = np.random.randn(0,10)
    y[0] = 0
    plt.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: I want to make a set of random (x,y) points, then draw lines from (0,0) to each of these in the simplest case, or from another set of points in another case.